# How can I escape an XML string and insert it as a value in JSON via jq?

Tags: json, xml, jq

I've got content in an XML file that looks like:

```
<blah abc="def">123</blah>
```

and a JSON string that looks like:

```
{
  "thj": "abc"
}
```

and I want to merge the XML into the JSON using jq to get something like

```
{
  "thj": "abc", 
  "xml": "&lt;blah abc=\"def\"&gt;123&lt;/blah&gt;"
}
```

(hopefully I've got that XML escaping correct...)

I'm trying commands like

```
echo $JSON_STRING | jq --slurpfile XML_CONTENT $XML_FILENAME --raw-input '@html' '.xml = "($XML_CONTENT)"'
```

and

```
echo $JSON_STRING | jq @html '.xml' <<< $XML_FILE_CONTENT
```

and

```
echo $JSON_STRING | jq --raw-input --slurpfile XML_CONTENT $XML_FILENAME '.xml = ($XML_CONTENT[0] | @html)
```

but I keep getting jq errors

I think I'm close to having the right answer... Help!

Comment: If you're getting errors: what are they? (And why are you applying both XML and JSON escaping when embedding the XML?)

Comment: @Richard I'm seeing errors like "jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACER (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1: version="1.0">". My wording of the question might be unclear - I'm trying to escape the XML and embed it as the value of a key:value pair inside some existing JSON

Comment: @monch1962 — But why do you want `&lt;` instead of `<`? `<` has no special meaning in JSON.

Comment: @Quentin - ah got it. Thanks for pointing that out. I've been looking at this for too long...

Comment: Please put the errors *in the question* so all the information is together (and not hidden away in comments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `--arg` to define a variable; you can use `"$(<...)"` to read a file and provide the argument.

```
echo "$JSON_STRING" | jq --arg xml "$(<"$XML_FILENAME")" '.xml=($xml | @html)'
```

However, you likely don't need XML escaping, as noted in comments; leaving that out gives you

```
echo "$JSON_STRING" | jq --arg xml "$(<"$XML_FILENAME")" '.xml=$xml'
```

EDIT: Typo in the second command.

Answer (score 1):

Use `-R` for reading XML content as raw text, and provide JSON string as an argument to jq.

```
jq -R --argjson jstr "$JSON_STRING" '$jstr + { "xml" : @html }' "$XML_FILENAME"
```

`@html` is a shorthand for `. | @html`.